# Can't open this word document. How to correct it?

Tags: microsoft-word

There is a problem in this document. I can't open it. I try it open in office 2013. Then I try to open it in google doc, but can't open. It shows a warning as I given below. Document properties given below. How I debug this document!

Can you give brief procedure to solve this?

[image: Problem window]

[image: Document properties]

Comment: What are the error details? It seems quite large for a Word doc, are there pictures in it also?

Comment: Can you hit details and give is the information from there? You can also try opening in Safe Mode. Hold down the CTRL key and it should prompt you to open in safe mode. Or go to Start and type: winword.exe /safe
From there File> Open > said document

Comment: Show what the details show or else if someone sent it to you via email, etc. then perhaps have them resend it. I've seen Word documents get corrupt in transit via SMTP email or FTP, etc. (firewalls stripping headers or whatever the case may be or just packet level corruption) and they just are recoverable or easily recoverable and getting another copy sent from the original source is the quickest solution. Without disclosing what the details show though, it's hard telling but that's a quick thought as well.